# DKIM hmailserver and NameCheap Setup

Tags: hmail-server, namecheap

I've been trying to setup my hmailserver with DKIM.

I was following this guide -> https://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=29402

And I created my keys with this site -> https://www.port25.com/dkim-wizard/

Domain name: linnabary.us

DomainKey Selector: dkim

Key size: 1024

I created a pem file;

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<key>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Saved it and loaded it into hmailserver

When I set this up on NameCheap I selected TXT Record, set my host as @, and put this line in, minus key of course;

```
v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=<KEY>
```

Now when I test with -> http://www.isnotspam.com

It says my DKIM key is as follows;

```
----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: invalid
ID(s) verified: header.From=admin@linnabary.us
Selector=
domain=
DomainKeys DNS Record=._domainkey.
```

I was wondering if I am making any obvious errors in my record.

Edit;

The email contains the following line;

```
dkim-signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; d=linnabary.us; s=dkim;
```

This is what the setup looks like on NameCheap;

[image]

And here is the next test email from ;

```
This message is an automatic response from isNOTspam's authentication verifier service. The service allows email senders to perform a simple check of various sender authentication mechanisms. It is provided free of charge, in the hope that it is useful to the email community. While it is not officially supported, we welcome any feedback you may have at .

Thank you for using isNOTspam.

The isNOTspam team

==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================

SPF Check : pass
Sender-ID Check : pass
DKIM Check : invalid
SpamAssassin Check : ham (non-spam)
==========================================================
Details:
==========================================================

HELO hostname: [69.61.241.46]
Source IP: 69.61.241.46
mail-from: admin@linnabary.us
Anonymous To: ins-a64wsfm3@isnotspam.com
---------------------------------------------------------
SPF check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: pass
ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=admin@linnabary.us
DNS record(s):
linnabary.us.   1799    IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:69.61.241.46 ~all"


----------------------------------------------------------
Sender-ID check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: pass

ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=admin@linnabary.us
DNS record(s):
linnabary.us.   1799    IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:69.61.241.46 ~all"


----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: invalid
ID(s) verified: header.From=admin@linnabary.us
Selector=
domain=
DomainKeys DNS Record=._domainkey.

----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin 3.4.1 (2015-04-28)

Result: ham (non-spam) (04.6points, 10.0 required)

pts rule name description
---- ---------------------- -------------------------------


* 3.5 BAYES_99 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* -0.0 SPF_HELO_PASS SPF: HELO matches SPF record
* -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
* 0.2 BAYES_999 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99.9 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
* valid
* 0.8 RDNS_NONE Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS
* 0.0 T_DKIM_INVALID DKIM-Signature header exists but is not valid
X-Spam-Status: Yes, hits=4.6 required=-20.0 tests=BAYES_99,BAYES_999,
DKIM_SIGNED,RDNS_NONE,SPF_HELO_PASS,SPF_PASS,T_DKIM_INVALID autolearn=no
autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
X-Spam-Score: 4.6

To learn more about the terms used in the SpamAssassin report, please search
here: http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/

==========================================================
Explanation of the possible results (adapted from 
draft-kucherawy-sender-auth-header-04.txt):
==========================================================

"pass"
the message passed the authentication test.

"fail"
the message failed the authentication test.

"softfail"
the message failed the authentication test, and the authentication
method has either an explicit or implicit policy which doesn't require
successful authentication of all messages from that domain.

"neutral"
the authentication method completed without errors, but was unable
to reach either a positive or a negative result about the message.

"temperror"
a temporary (recoverable) error occurred attempting to authenticate
the sender; either the process couldn't be completed locally, or
there was a temporary failure retrieving data required for the
authentication. A later retry may produce a more final result.

"permerror"
a permanent (unrecoverable) error occurred attempting to
authenticate the sender; either the process couldn't be completed
locally, or there was a permanent failure retrieving data required
for the authentication.


==========================================================
Original Email
==========================================================

From admin@linnabary.us Wed Apr 12 17:41:22 2017
Return-path: <admin@linnabary.us>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on isnotspam.com
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Level: ****
X-Spam-Report: 
* 3.5 BAYES_99 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* -0.0 SPF_HELO_PASS SPF: HELO matches SPF record
* -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
* 0.2 BAYES_999 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99.9 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
* valid
* 0.8 RDNS_NONE Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS
* 0.0 T_DKIM_INVALID DKIM-Signature header exists but is not valid
X-Spam-Status: Yes, hits=4.6 required=-20.0 tests=BAYES_99,BAYES_999,
DKIM_SIGNED,RDNS_NONE,SPF_HELO_PASS,SPF_PASS,T_DKIM_INVALID autolearn=no
autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
Envelope-to: ins-a64wsfm3@isnotspam.com
Delivery-date: Wed, 12 Apr 2017 17:41:22 +0000
Received: from [69.61.241.46] (helo=linnabary.us)
by localhost.localdomain with esmtp (Exim 4.84_2)
(envelope-from <admin@linnabary.us>)
id 1cyMGg-0007x2-1Q
for ins-a64wsfm3@isnotspam.com; Wed, 12 Apr 2017 17:41:22 +0000
dkim-signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; d=linnabary.us; s=dkim;
c=relaxed/relaxed; q=dns/txt; h=From:Subject:Date:Message-ID:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding;
bh=Ns4aRUgWUtil4fiVnvitgeV+q1K/smEYtRGN497S5Ew=;
b=Nc2Kzrzas0QqMpWM4fnF5o5wLWlWYFxlGlAipe+85H9cwGgc4hvEKUj1UvgB6I2VHUbJ0OGN/sJO9tjWgwlGypaUuW7Q8x/iI0UtC6cn7X6ZLHT+K6A2A6MdoyR1NF4xxvqPadcmcQwnrY0Tth4ycydpQMlBCZS30sc1qUjUrN0=
Received: from [192.168.1.12] (Aurora [192.168.1.12])
by linnabary.us with ESMTPA
; Wed, 12 Apr 2017 13:41:28 -0400
To: ins-a64wsfm3@isnotspam.com
From: Admin <admin@linnabary.us>
Subject: Welcome to Linnabary
Message-ID: <8e8be6cd-6354-aeb9-b577-2b0efc25a1a1@linnabary.us>
Date: Wed, 12 Apr 2017 13:41:28 -0400
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101
Thunderbird/45.8.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-DKIM-Status: invalid (pubkey_unavailable)
I honestly have no idea what I should put in here in order to protect 
myself from filters, so I'm just making it up as I go.

- Tad
```

Comment: I can't see a TXT record for `dkim._domainkey.linnabary.us`. How does the signature of a test email look? Does it contain the correct domain (`d=linnabary.us`) and selector (`s=dkim`)? Also, **don't use online tools to generate secret keys**! Use `openssl` or similar to generate them on your machine. The site you link to sends you a public/private key pair in the response of a POST request. Even if they say they don't save it, there is no way to check wheather they really don't, so that key should be seen as compromised already when you get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Host* value for your TXT entry should just be `dkim._domainkey`. Currently your domain key is located at: `dkim._domainkey.linnabary.us.linnabary.us`, so you're not supposed to add the domain here.

That's why the response to the test email says `X-DKIM-Status: invalid (pubkey_unavailable)` - the public key can't be found where it is supposed to be.